# Bitcoin-qt doesn't get a server connection?

Tags: bitcoind, linux, cryptography, c++

I have created a new altcoin, and I run a server on one machine and connect bitcoin-qt on another machine. In this case it's blink the network connection, sometimes it shows one connection and after sometime it will disconnect and again show connected. What is the issue with that and how I can resolve that issue?

Comment: The most likely reason would be that this bitcoin-qt you're using is, well, for bitcoins, and not the altcoin you created. That means it'll connect then disconnect over and over and over, assuming you have it on addnode or connect in conf file. ....Judging by the question, I'm guessing the source wasn't changed & probably some 'alt-coin generator' was used. Could be wrong.

Comment: @JamesEze make this an answer, mate!